# CART (classification and regression tree) model prediction error message in R says - more items are supplied than to be assigned

Tags: r, tree, data-science, data-modeling, decision-tree

I got stuck on the CART model in R. My data set has about 7000 rows, 50 columns. I split the dataset to 75% training and 25% testing data, so my training set has 5658 rows and my test set has 1886 rows.

First i created a CART model with a few features in training dataset, which went through and the tree looked all good. Next I tried to apply this model to the testing data, but an error message always showed as below when the very last line of code was run. I have also attached a screenshot.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(111)
cart_sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(cart), size = floor(.75*nrow(cart)), replace = F)
cart_train <- cart[cart_sample, ]
cart_test  <- cart[-cart_sample, ]

# Build the model1
# Set cp = 0.01
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)

model1 <- price ~ neighbourhood_group + property_type + room_type + accommodates + bedrooms + bathrooms + amenities_ac + amenities_petsallowed + amenities_freeparking
tree1 <- rpart(formula = model1, data = cart_train, control = rpart.control(cp = 0.01))
rpart.plot(tree1)

# Predict using test dataset
cart_test$pred1_price <- predict(tree1, data = cart_test)
```

Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : Supplied 5658 items to be assigned to 1886 items of column 'pred1_price'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.

[code and error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLjqR.png)

I don't understand why there is an error. The size and training set and test set does not have to be equal. What am i missing?

Comment: Kindly provide a reproducible code using reprex package. https://www.tidyverse.org/help/

Comment: You have used the wrong argument name in predict. It should be `cart_test$pred1_price <- predict(tree1, newdata = cart_test)` . . .    newdata not data

Comment: @G5W it worked! thank you so much.